# Order one field both ASC and DESC

Tags: mysql, sorting, datetime

I've got a table with events that I'd like to show. I want to sort my events in the future ascending, and the past in descending order. How can I do this with one query?

My current order

```
Dec 23
Nov 10
Nov 04
Sep 12
Aug 01
Jul 23
```

The order I want

```
Nov 4 ** changed place
Nov 10
Dec 23 ** changed place
Sep 12
Aug 01
Jul 23
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share with us what you have tried.

Comment: can you explain more `The order I want` ? future asc and past desc ? not understand ..

Comment: As you can see in the example first example, the dates are queried from the datebase with an ordinary `ORDER BY eventDate DESC` which means the dates are just displayed in a descending order. I want the dates that are in the future to be displayed ascending - sort of `WHERE eventDate >= NOW() ORDER BY eventDate ASC` - and the dates in the past to be displayed descending - `WHERE eventDate < NOW() ORDER BY eventDate DESC`. This however requires two queries, and I want to know if there is a way to this in one query? @JayBlanchard @anant-dabhi

Comment: @wally you should remove the PHP tag, you are asking for a single mysql query, not involving PHP in any way. +1 for a good question tho! This is where people try to use two order by's in a UNION select.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Thanks, I'm still new to stack overflow... I tried using `UNION` but it didn't work. The future dates displayed as DESC and the past dates as ASC, not the other way around. No matter how I changed the ASC/DESC, the order stayed the same. My query was `(SELECT * FROM events WHERE eventDate >= NOW() ORDER BY eventDate ASC )
UNION
(SELECT * FROM events WHERE eventDate < NOW() ORDER BY eventDate DESC )`

Comment: I ment to say that people (unsuccessfully) try UNION - it doesn't support ordering the resultsets differently.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are asking to sort by the distance from current date:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
ORDER BY IF(date_field >= NOW()),0,1), ABS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), date_field))
```

Comment: Please use the code formatting and add an explanation to your code-only answer.

Comment: This would interweave the results, not keep them seperated.

Comment: Although it does form part of the answer, could do `ORDER BY IF(eventDate >= NOW()),0,1) ASC, days ASC` to first sepate them out, THEN sort by the distance.

Comment: By combining @barryhunter and Mareks answers I managed to get the result I wanted - thanks! Do you have any idea on how if-statements in queries affect the speed of the query? I have a weird feeling it takes a lot longer to run the queries.

Comment: Surely the time the query takes is something you can easily MEASURE, no need for gut feelings! But regardless, it will almost certainly be slower, as the query is more complicated. The expression will need to be computed for every row - before ordering. And will prevent the use indexes to perform the order by. Learn about EXPLAIN  :)

Comment: @wally To increase speed it would help to limit the result set before ordering. For example if you you are sure there would be no result displayed more distant than one month from now, put this condition into where clause.